# What is the correct location for redirection method for Facebook OAuth “Unsupported” in Chrome on iOS fix?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform

I have this section of code, which addresses the Chrome mobile issue for Facebook authentication of users when you use the Facebook login workflow for Parse.com JavaScript

https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-facebook-users

```
// fix iOS Chrome
    if( navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS') )
        window.open('https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id='+490518664444605+'&redirect_uri='+ document.location.href +'&scope=email,public_profile', '', null);
    else
        Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
            //scope: 'email,public_profile'
        });
```

The source of this workaround can be found here
https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#users-facebook-users

What I'm unable to understand is where can I insert this fix existing code ? I've tried several locations within the code block, but as of yet i'm unable to achieve the desired results

Can any one advice please?

Existing code

```
    //check user session and refresh it
    var uri = encodeURI('http://xxxxcom/home.html');
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //user is authorized
            document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
            getUserData();

        } else {
            //user is not authorized
        }
    });
};

//load the JavaScript SDK
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


//add event listener to login button
document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    //do the login
var uri = encodeURI('http://xxxxx.com/home.html');
Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
    success: function(user) {
        if (!user.existed()) {
                window.location.href=uri;
        } else {
            window.location = encodeURI("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxx&redirect_uri="+uri+"&response_type=token");


        }
    },
    error: function(user, error) {

    }


});



}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution for ios facebook website login in google chrome . Actually the issue was with google chrome in ios when we click on facebook login button it give internally null to the window.open in ios chrome .

**There are two solution-**
**First-** either to check it is chrome in ios(chrios) and then generate custom login screen ( still not chance that it will we correct ).
**Second-** what i have used. Is to use facebook login from backhand create a api hit will populate facebook screen and then when login is done it will redirect to your server from where you will redirect to your website page with facebook data.
**Another benefit** of it is that you can create 2 website for same website owner (you can not set two website url in facebook developer account) .In this way you can create many website facebook login with same facebook appid .